# Feature importances in Panel Data Models

Tags: regression, normalization, feature-selection, panel-data

We know that the size of coefficient in the linear regression model doesn't show its importance.
In a linear regression I can assess feature importances by scaling the data. Can I apply such a method for panel data models: particularly for pooled regression, fixed and random effects models? If I can, why is it valid?

Tried to find information on the Internet but there's nothing there